# MYSQL Syntax Error LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having issues trying to figure out this syntax error. Heres the SQL query:

### SQL QUERY

```
SELECT oh.date_modified, oh.physicianNote, os.name AS status
FROM order oh 
LEFT JOIN order_status os ON oh.order_status_id = os.order_status_id
WHERE oh.order_id = '118' AND os.language_id = '1'
ORDER BY oh.date_added ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

### SQL ERROR

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order oh LEFT JOIN order_status os ON oh.order_status_id =
>   os.order_status_i' at line 2

Not really sure whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 7):

`ORDER` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  Quote it in backticks:

```
SELECT   oh.date_modified, oh.physicianNote, os.name AS status
FROM     `order` oh LEFT JOIN order_status os USING (order_status_id)
WHERE    oh.order_id = '118' AND os.language_id = '1'
ORDER BY oh.date_added
LIMIT    0,10
```

Answer (score 1):

**"ORDER"** is reserved word. This is error. Use the word **order** Quote in backticks